# Menu control in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, editing-menu

Is it possible to have a top menu in sharepoint like when i click on the tab it should provide me a mega menu.Is it possible through OOB of sharepoint..please share your ideas..

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB way to do this, but it can certainly be done with CSS and/or JavaScript.